# Passing a struct through cgo

Tags: c, go, cgo

I am using cgo to call c from go. I want to pass a struct through the function.
In my c file it looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(TestStruct val) {
  printf(val);
}
```

In my go file i am doing this:

```
package main

// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -I/usr/lib/
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/lib/ -lstdc++
//#include <file.c>
import "C"

type TestStruct struct {
  val  string
  type string
}

func main() {
  var value = TestStruct{ "foo", "bar" }

  C.test(value);
}
```

but this doesn't work. It throws this error:

> could not determine kind of name for C.test

Comment: besides the C code not knowing the correct type, a Go string is not a C string, and you cannot pass values containing Go allocated pointers to C.

Answer (score 0):

`TestStruct` is not defined in the C code. Try adding a definition.

You'll also need to use cgo's C strings rather than Go's built-in string in the struct.

As an aside: There's two more mistakes in your C code. `printf(val)` does not work because `printf` can not be used to directly print a struct. Also, you should **never** use use anything but a string literal for `printf`'s first argument for safety reasons. Replace that line by something like `puts(val.val)` or `printf("%s", val.val)`.